# Correction of a solution

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $a_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R$ with $a_i\geq 0$.If $\sum_1^\infty 1/(1+a_n)<\infty$ then show that $\sum_1^\infty 1/(1+x_na_n)<\infty $ for each real sequence $x_1,x_2...$ with $x_i\geq 0$ and lim inf$_{ n\rightarrow \infty}x_n>0$.

My approach:$\sum_1^\infty 1/(1+a_n)<\infty$ then the sequence $S_n$ of partial sums is bounded

$S_n=\sum_1^n 1/(1+a_n)<\infty$

$Q_n=\sum_1^n 1/(1+x_na_n)<\sum_1^\infty 1/(1+a_n)<\infty$
Thus $Q_n$is also bounded
Thus the series converges.But one hypothesis has not been used.Where am I wrong?

Comment: It is not true in general that $\sum \frac{1}{1+x_na_n}\leq \sum \frac1{1+a_n}$, since it can happen that $x_n<1$. Here is exactly where hypothesis $\liminf_n x_n>0$ should be used.

Comment: Ok thanks but how this hypothesis shows that $x_n\geq 1$@Milly

Comment: what you have is only $\liminf_n x_n >0$ (e.g. $x_n\equiv 0.01$ satisfies your hypothesis)... Here use limit comparison test between $\frac{1}{1+a_n}$ and $\frac{1}{1+x_na_n}$, and $\liminf_n x_n$ will appear as bound for ratio.